# Can i plot a graph with only links in a json file in case of D3?

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I want to get a list of nodes from links data in JSON file.
Later I would like to plot a graph with links and edges.

My sample json file:

```
{
    "links": [
        { "source":0, "target":1, "value":20, "orientation":"down" },
        { "source":1, "target":2, "value":1, "orientation":"left" },
        { "source":2, "target":3, "value":1, "orientation":"right" }
    ]
}
```

my JS function:

```
$(function() {

    var width = 500,
        height = 300;

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

    var force = d3.layout.force()
        .gravity(.05)
        .distance(100)
        .charge(-100)
        .size([width, height]);

    d3.json("test_1.json", function(error, json) {
        if (error) throw error;

        var count = 0;
        var nodes = [];


        json.links.forEach(function(e) { 
            count++;
            nodes.push({name: "test_"+e.source, orientation: e.orientation});
        });
        console.log("Count is :  "+count);  


        force
            .nodes(json.nodes)
            .links(json.links)
            .start();

        var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
            .data(json.links)
            .enter().append("line")
            .attr("class", "link");

        var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
           .data(json.nodes)
           .attr("class", "node")
           .call(force.drag);

        node.append("circle")
           .attr("class", "node")
           .attr("r", 5);


        force.on("tick", function() {
             link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
                 .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
                 .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
                 .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

             node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
        });
    });
});
```

I cannot get a list from the function though as there seems to be an error with the forEach method of JSON.

Could anyone please help?

**UPDATE**: added the complete code.

**Error:** *Cannot read property 'weight' of undefined.*

So i added some nodes in my JSON because i think d3 always expects a node.

Comment: in the json you have posted there is no nodes so _json.nodes_ is undefined..which is the root cause of the problem

Comment: You're refferencing to a non-existing field of JSON called 'nodes'. You should work with 'links' array.
Smth like:
`json.links.forEach( ... )`

Comment: yes..that is right. Now I can add nodes to my array but not able to plot. Is this because my json does not have nodes? Can i add this via JS?

Comment: Could you please provide us with all code you're working with?

Comment: i just updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I could find a way to do it:

my JSON file:

```
[
    {"source":"entry","target":"chocolate","value":20,"orientation":"down","x": 200, "y": 150},
    {"source":"chocolate","target":"bread","value":1,"orientation":"left","x": 140, "y": 300},
     {"source":"bread","target":"soap","value":1,"orientation":"right","x": 400, "y": 190}
    ]
```

my JS code:

```
var width = 960,
    height = 500;
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);
var force = d3.layout.force()
    .size([width, height])
    .linkDistance(20)
    .charge(-500);

d3.json("name.json", function(error, links) {
  if (error) throw error;
  var nodesByName = {};
  // Create nodes for each unique source and target.
  links.forEach(function(link) {
    link.source = nodeByName(link.source);
    link.target = nodeByName(link.target);
  });
  // Extract the array of nodes from the map by name.
  var nodes = d3.values(nodesByName);
  // Create the link lines.
  var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
      .data(links)
    .enter().append("line")
      .attr("class", "link");
  // Create the node circles.

  var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("r", 4.5)
      .call(force.drag); 

  // Start the force layout.
  force
      .nodes(nodes)
      .links(links)
      .on("tick", tick)
      .start();

  function tick() {
    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });
    node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
  }
  function nodeByName(name) {
    return nodesByName[name] || (nodesByName[name] = {name: name});
  }
});
});
```

It can draw the required layout.

- Reference: https://gist.github.com/mbostock/2949937

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As far as you assign newly created nodes array to `nodes` variable you should pass it to your force layout, not `links.nodes`.

```
force
    .nodes(nodes)
    .links(json.links)
    .start();
```

Or just add it to `links` object

```
...
json.links.forEach(function(e) { 
    count++;
    nodes.push({name: "test_"+e.source, orientation: e.orientation});
});

links.nodes = nodes;
...
```

Comment: yes this works but again there is a "weight error due to less number of nodes. I need an additional node which is target:3. This means for 3 links which i have in my JSON, i need to have 4 nodes. I am not sure how to get last entry of json and add additional node.